# What's the 'present simple' form of the word "нашла́" in 3rd person singular female?

Tags: глаголы

What's the 'present simple' form of the word "нашла́" in 3rd person singular female?

For example:

> She **finds** a new toy every week.

I look for this word [in a table of this verb](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) and it's not obvious for me in which form of the verb I should use in this case.

Should it be

> Oна **найдёт** новую игрушку каждую неделю.

?

Answer (score 23):

No, it shouldn't, a different verb should be used here -- "находить". The 3rd person singular form of this verb is "находит".

The difference between those two verbs is the aspect. "Найти" is a perfective verb, while "находить" is imperfective. Imperfective verbs are usually used in place of English present simple tense.
So, the correct translation should be "Она находит новую игрушку каждую неделю."

Also, on a side note, perfective verbs have no present tense at all, and the form you put in is actually future. And verbs don't conjugate for gender in present and future tenses.

Answer (score 1):

Находит.

> Она находит новую игрушку каждую неделю.